# How to show tooltip message for custom directive in vs code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have created one custom directive like app-subscriber.If i mouse over on  I want to show tool tip message like "This is for subscriber and need mail id". How we can do it? is it possible? Need to create new vs code extension?

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-qeasdu-7kqv5z?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

There's diagnostics and hover overlays you can render.

Take a peek here, is this the sort of functionality you're seeking?

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features#show-hovers

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Material Tooltip](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/examples) for this. I see you already installed Angular Material so all you need to do is:

1. Import BrowserAnimationsModule in your AppModule
2. Import MatTooltipModule in your AppModule
3. use it in your component template like so: `matTooltip="This is for subscriber and need mail id"` on the element that should show the tooltip.

[Updated Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-qeasdu-lvrutv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsubscriber%2Fsubscriber.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I am expecting in vs code not in browser. Same like this:https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Infragistics.igniteui-angular-tooltips